# Segmentation fault when calling a function which contains an image as parameter opencv / c++

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault

I'm implementing a method that decompose the images and I have a segmentation fault error ,I'm going to start by showing you the debugger output :

```
#0  0x0804c2cb in cv::Mat::Mat (this=0xbffff110, m=...)
      at /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:117
#1  0x0804ad14 in decompose (input=...) at main.cpp:241
#2  0x0804bbd7 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbffff6c4) at main.cpp:322
```

Here's a portion of my code :

```
#define MAX_ITERATIONS 15
//////////////////
/////////////////
float sum(cv::Mat img, int startedY, int startedX, int w) {
    float res = 0.0f;
for (int j = startedY - ((w - 1) / 2) ; j < startedY + ((w + 1) / 2); j++)
for (int i = startedX - ((w - 1) / 2); i < startedX + ((w + 1) / 2); i++) {
        {
  if ((i >= 0 && i < img.size().width) && (j >= 0  && j < img.size().height)) {  res += img.at<float>(j,i);
            }}}   return res; }

 cv::Mat decompose(cv::Mat input)
{
 /////////////
 cv::Mat inputImg(input)
 ///////////////////
 cv::Mat imgSource(inputImg);
 cv::Mat imgMax(inputImg);
 cv::Mat newImgMax(imgMax.size().height,imgMax.size().width,CV_32F);
 ////////////////////////////////
 ////////////////////////////////////
for (int l = 0; l < imgSource.size().width; l++){
 for (int k = 0; k < imgSource.size().height; k++){
   if( (k >= 0 && k < imgSource.size().height) && (l >= 0  && l <    
          imgSource.size().width) ) {
  newImgMax.at<float>(k,l) = (float)sum(imgMax,k, l, wmax) / (wmax * wmax);***LIGNE 241*********
 }}}
 ////////////////////
/////////////////////

****************************************************************** 
cv::Mat imgMoyenne(inputImg);

for (int i = 0; i < inputImg.size().height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < inputImg.size().width; j++) {
       imgMoyenne.at<float>(i, j) = (newImgMin.at<float>(i, j) +   
          newImgMax.at<float>(i, j)) /2;
    }
}
Mat diff_im=inputImg - imgMoyenne; 

return diff_im; //the end of the decomposition function
  }

 *************************************************************
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char modeTitle[30]= {0}, residueTitle[50];
    double variance = 1000000;
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: ./emd <image>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
 cv::Mat inputImg;
 cv::Mat imgMode;

 inputImg=imread(argv[1]); 
 if(! inputImg.data )                             
    {cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1; }

  namedWindow("Source Image",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  imshow("Source Image",inputImg);
  cv::waitKey(1000);
    for (int i = 1; i < MAX_ITERATIONS + 1; i++) {
        sprintf(modeTitle, "BEMC-%d", i);
        std::cout << "Decomposing " << modeTitle << std::endl;
        imgMode = decompose(inputImg);**************LIGNE 322****************
       //////////////
       /////////////
     }
```

here's a portion of /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp :

```
inline Mat::Mat(const Mat& m)
: flags(m.flags), dims(m.dims), rows(m.rows), cols(m.cols), data(m.data),
refcount(m.refcount), datastart(m.datastart), dataend(m.dataend),
datalimit(m.datalimit), allocator(m.allocator), size(&rows)
{
if( refcount )
    CV_XADD(refcount, 1);**************** LIGNE 117******************
if( m.dims <= 2 )
{
    step[0] = m.step[0]; step[1] = m.step[1];
}
else
{
    dims = 0;
    copySize(m);
}
}
```

Any ideas how I could fix this issue?

Comment: The first rule of C++ programming is: "just because you crashed in one spot, it doesn't mean that's where the bug is". Please edit your question, and include a [mcve], with the emphasis on both the "minimum" and "complete" requirements. Your question fails on both.

Answer (score 2):

I have not found `return` statement in `cv::Mat decompose(cv::Mat input)` method (this should have produced warnings and may be the root cause of the issue). Also it looks like this code should not be compilable as `inputImg` should not be accessible here:

```
 cv::Mat decompose(cv::Mat input)
{
 ///////////////////
 cv::Mat imgSource(inputImg);
 cv::Mat imgMax(inputImg);
...
}
```

Comment: I was going to comment on the `input`-`inputImg` shuffle. If this compiles, OP may have a wider scope `inputImg` causing grief. Hard to say with only a snippet of code.

Comment: @user4581301 yes, this may be the case

Comment: I have a return statement,I just put the most important lignes and the program is compilable @s0urcer

Comment: the inputImg is initialised by Input I have this ligne cv::Mat inputImg(input); in the beginning

Comment: @ImaneElMourabit then probably I would agree with comments above that you should provide the actual code. Also it looks like width and height are confused in for loops.

Comment: @s0urcer the whole program is long,that's why I put just a portion but if you want I can edit the question and put all the code

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that the input image to your function is of type `CV_32FC1`, since you're accessing it's values as `.at<float>`.

However, `inputImg` from `imread` will be  of type `CV_8UC3`.

You need to convert `inputImage` to `CV_32FC1` format before passing it to `decompose`:

```
 // read the image...

 // From 3 to 1 channels
 cvtColor(inputImage, inputImage, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

 // From CV_8U to CV_32F
 inputImage.convertTo(inputImage, CV_32F);

 // now you can enter the for loop...
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer,it solved the problem but my program generates a new segmentation fault in returning the result of decomposition                                                                                                          `cv::Mat decompose(cv::Mat input)
{ cv::Mat inputImg(input);
///////////////////////////
////////////////////                                                                                                     
Mat diff_im=inputImg - imgMoyenne;    
    `

Comment: there's no return statement. Add `return newImgMax;` at the end of the function

Comment: thank you very much for your answer,it solved the problem but my program generates a new segmentation fault in returning the result of decomposition                                                                                                      `cv::Mat decompose(cv::Mat input)
{ cv::Mat inputImg(input);///////////////cv::Mat imgMoyenne(inputImg);  /////                                                                                                                             Mat diff_im=inputImg - imgMoyenne;    
 /////////// return diff_im;  } it crashes in the return statement  `

Comment: Unless you provide some code that I can copy & paste & run (see what's a [mcve]), there isn't much more we can do...

Comment: The whole program is long,that's why I put just a portion